# How To Use .NET Core ResponseCaching

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core, cache-control

I have a .NET Core Web API that simply fetches some data from a database. I want to use some caching solution to prevent going database for every request and also to increase performance. I followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0) from Microsoft. 
 I added

```
app.UseResponseCaching();
```

to Configure method in Startup.cs and also added

```
services.AddResponseCaching();
```

to ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

In the API Controller, I added ResponseCache attribute as below.

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 43200)]
public ActionResult GetCoffees()
{
    // some service calls
    return OK(someCoffees);
}
```

So, if I use Postman for testing I can see that it is cached.
[image: cached response from server]

But whenever I use a browser e.g Chrome, the browser always sends (I think it's a default behaviour) "Cache-Control: max-age=0" header so that the response caching does not work as expected.

[image: request headers that include Cache-Control: max-age=0]

The documentation says,

> When testing and troubleshooting caching behavior, a browser may set request headers that affect caching in undesirable ways. For example, a browser may set the Cache-Control header to no-cache or max-age=0 when refreshing a page. The following tools can explicitly set request headers and are preferred for testing caching: Fiddler, Postman

So, considering all this, how can I use ResponseCaching approach or should I use another type of caching mechanism? If ResponseCaching is not suitable for my goal, what is the use case of ResponseCaching?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using in-memory Cache or distributed caching. This approach does not rely on Client's request headers to control the Cache, which is what you seem to be trying to achieve.

ResponseCaching in ASP.NET Core relies on the Request Headers set by the Client to control the Caching behavior. So it is not consistent across different clients, you have already seen this in the Postman vs Chrome example.

Microsoft's Article about Response Caching says the following.

> Response caching reduces the number of requests a client or proxy makes to a web server. Response caching also reduces the amount of work the web server performs to generate a response. Response caching is controlled by headers that specify how you want client, proxy, and middleware to cache responses.

> The ResponseCache attribute participates in setting response caching headers. Clients and intermediate proxies should honor the headers for caching responses under the HTTP 1.1 Caching specification.

You can follow the following articles and choose what suits you best.

[Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0)